# Windows 8 applications shows offline and not able to install any new application

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-store-app

I have installed Windows 8 release preview.

I've broadband connection and I'm able to surf or open any site from any browser in my PC.

I am facing internet connection error in all applications. While I am trying to open any application, that shows me "Offline" and says that "Connect to internet connection".

May be for this error I can not able to install any new application from app. store.

Comment: is any firewall blocking those applications?

Comment: i don't think so... i can able to browse using IE(application). Still if you know such a settings then please let me know so i can work on it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of IE working alongside a program not being connected?